# Unable to create a blank working bridge.net project via visual studio template

Tags: bridge.net

Everytime I try to create a bridge.net new project I get the following error:

> Could not add all required packages to the project. The following
>   packages failed to install from [the user appdata local
>   folder]\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14\extensions\IJHDC25V.XOU\Packages.
>
> Bridge.1.10.0 : Solution is not opened or not saved. Please ensure you
>   have an open and saved solution.

Trying to build the project leads to the 'Bridge' namespace missing.

I did the following:

1. Download the bridge.net .vsix package from
   https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dca5c80f-a0df-4944-8343-9c905db84757
2. Run the package
3. Create a new project -> Bridge.net -> Class Library
4. Named the project 'Demo'

I verified the folder exists and is populated. I've tried running Visual studio as an administrator and as a standard user.

How do I get a working blank Bridge.net project with the visual studio template?

Comment: If this is still an issue for anyone, please try with latest Bridge release. There has been some updates to the installation process, and those changes may have helped solve this problem. Current release as of now: 1.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this doesn't quite answer precisely the question asked but I don't use the VSIX package to create Bridge.NET projects, I just create a new (standard) class library and then use NuGet to add "Bridge". This adds the Bridge compiler and it adds a "demo.html" file and a basic "bridge.json" config file to get you started. (If you wanted to write a Bridge library and you didn't want the "starter park" items then you can add the NuGet package "Bridge.Min" instead).

Answer (score 0):

The project needs to be saved to disk.

In `Visual Studio` under `Tools / Options / Projects and Solutions` tick the `Save new projects when created` checkbox.

Then create a new project.